# Hosted blazor assembly conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

My solution structure is hosted blazor webassembly template :

//Clinet Part 
BlazorApp 
ClientModel

//Server Part 
ServerCoreApp 
ServerModel

//template of this project is "shared project" and cannot [compile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows) 
SharedProject

I have razor pages on server side and blazor client at the same time

Shared project has class 'ClassA' and I added it to ClientModel and ServerModel as linked items.
with debugging symbol, I changed some behavior of ClassA on client or server
for example

```
#if AspCore
    Console.Writeline("Server Project");
#else
    Console.Writeline("Client Project");
#endif
```

I dont have any problem on debugging. but after publish solution I got error for linked class conflict

> The type 'ClassA' exists in both 'ClientModel,Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' and 'ServerModel, Version=1.0.0.2, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null'

this happened on razor pages because we cannot define extern alias on razor pages

Comment: @HenkHolterman I dont want to execute same code on server and client. I want to execute custom code based on platform. in this example I have two platform, but in real solution, I have additional platforms like xamarin, wpf, silverlight ... and every platform has its #if symbol

Comment: @HenkHolterman shared project is not compiled. it is "shared project" type. it is a file inventory and it is not have any output like exe or dll. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=windows

Comment: @HenkHolterman I removed default shared project and added another  project as "shared project" type that cannot compiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found solution
on debug, visual studio can find assemblies correctly and when we publish project, assembly resolver cannot find correct assembly and raises conflict error.

so, we must add two reference of Blazor app to Server app
1- a reference for debug purpose as

```
<ProjectReference Include="..\Client\BlazorApp.csproj" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'" />
```

2- a reference for publish

```
 <ProjectReference Include="..\Client\BlazorApp.csproj" ReferenceOutputAssembly="False" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'" />
```

then on publishing, visual studio does not copy client app dlls on root of publish folder and all of client dlls is exists on wwwroot_content and wwwroot_framework folder and no conflict raised.

another solution is delete all client-only dlls from root of published folder. but we must do it every time after publishing